# Where should I put API calls?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Fairly new to React Native, I would like to apply proper "good practices" to my first project. I'm trying to build an Hacker News client.

You can find it here: https://github.com/napolux/hnative and as you can see I'm at the very beginning of my project.

I'm willing to separate the API calls I made to get the news from the component [ItemList](https://github.com/napolux/hnative/blob/master/app/components/ItemsList.js) where they currently are. My goals is to maximize code reuse.

In pseudo-code, this is what I do:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.makeApiRequest();
}

makeApiRequest = () => {
    // Ask for data
    // Save data in component state
}

render = () => {
    // Use data to render stuff...
}
```

I'm still puzzled by redux and I'm still not sure if it can fit my needs in any way and help me to organize my code.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track. The most common mistake is to put your API calls in the `componentWillMount` lifecycle hook, but you're smarter than most people :)

As with most things, the correct answer though is going to be a dissatisfying "it depends". As you're just getting started, I think you're on the right track though. Keep it simple until simple becomes difficult to manage, then refactor to solve for that complexity.

There are several strategies you can employ. I think you've started with the right "first step". Here are a couple other strategies you might want to investigate though when the time is right.

### Container Components

You're basically wrapping your stateless components in a container responsible for fetching the needed data. This would be your logical "next step". Here's a few articles I have bookmarked on the topic.

- https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-container-components/
- https://voice.kadira.io/let-s-compose-some-react-containers-3b91b6d9b7c8#.qgg1i13vp
- http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/react-js-presentational-container-components

### API Helper

This is a strategy I learned from Tyler McGinnis and used on one of my first projects. You'd basically put all your API calls into a single, helper file. When you need to make a call out to an API, you just import it and use it. You could easily combine this with the Container strategy above if you wanted.

- https://github.com/geirman/RepairMaps/tree/master/App/Utils

### Redux

Redux should be your last stop. This adds a lot of boilerplate to the project and comes at a cost. Keep it simple until you need to solve the problems Redux is really good at solving. How do you know when that is? Dan Abromov wrote a great article on it, so I'll let him tell you so you can make the trade offs yourself.

- https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into [mobx](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-mobx) . You can place your API calls in mobx **@action** methods